# How can I find all radio buttons within the same logical "group" using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-traversing

I'm writing some code that highlights all `<input type=radio />` within a "radio group" when any one of them is changed.
In the event handler for the radio "change" event, I use the following code to find all other similar radios:

```
radioHandler: function (event) {
    var element = $(this);
    var name = element.attr("name");
    // Find all radios in the same group:
    element.closest("form")
        .find("input[type=radio][name='" + name + "']")
        .each(function(){
            ... etc ...
        });
},
```

This works perfectly if the radios are indeed contained within a form.
However, I also want it to work if there are radios **outside** the form too.

For example, assuming all radios use the same `name`, the following represents 3 different radio groups (and all browsers behave this way):

```
       o Radio A | o Radio B | o Radio C          (Group - no form)
<form> o Radio D | o Radio E | o Radio F </form>  (Group - form 1)
<form> o Radio G | o Radio H | o Radio I </form>  (Group - form 2)
```

#### If I have an element, what's the best way to find ONLY the radios that are part of its "group"?

Also, for bonus points ... what if the element isn't part of the current document -- ie, it is contained within another "detached" context?  The current solution works fine (because `element.closest(...)` uses the element's context).

Comment: Why don't you just put all the groups in a certain type of container? There is no way to solve this without unacceptable performance penalty.

Comment: @Esailija Well maybe that's the correct answer? However, this doesn't seem too crazy, there's gotta be a decent solution.

Comment: Helped me solve something a lot similar after six years of this post! Cheers Scott!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of executing the .find on your form, execute it on your entire document:

```
$("input[type=radio][name='" + name + "']").each(function() {
    ... etc ...
});
```

Unless I'm not understanding the question here?

**EDIT** I didn't test the code below but it might give you the idea on how to do it.

```
radioHandler: function (event) {
    var element = $(this);
    var name = element.attr("name");
    // Find all radios in the same group:
    if (element.parents().find("form").length > 0) {
        name.closest("form").find("input[type=radio][name='" + name + "']")
        .each(function(){
            ... etc ...
        });
    } else {
        $("input[type=radio][name='" + name + "']").each(function() {
            if (!$(this).parents().find("form").length) {
                ... etc ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the radio is inside a form, I want radios inside the form.  If the radio is outside the form, I want radios outside any forms.  If I have an element, I want to find ONLY the radios that are part of its "group".

Comment: @ScottRippey Alright, give the above code a try or have a look at it as it might give you the general idea of how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think outside the box. Add a non-standard attribute to the `<input type="radio" />` tags that are outside the `<form>`. For example:

```
<input type="radio" outsideform="true" />
```

Then use a JQuery selector like this:

```
$('input[type=radio][outsideform=true]')
```

You could also do something similar with a CSS class. The class doesn't have to actually implement any styles.

```
<input type="radio" class="outsideform" />
```

...with...

```
$('input[type=radio].outsideform')
```

Comment: Thanks, the class idea is decent.  I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin, though, so I'd like it to be easier to use than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the jquery-ui.js file (my version 1.11.4) you can see that internally they use this function to get all radio buttons that are in the same group:

```
radioGroup = function( radio ) {
 var name = radio.name,
  form = radio.form,
  radios = $( [] );
 if ( name ) {
  name = name.replace( /'/g, "\\'" );
  if ( form ) {
   radios = $( form ).find( "[name='" + name + "'][type=radio]" );
  } else {
   radios = $( "[name='" + name + "'][type=radio]", radio.ownerDocument )
    .filter(function() {
     return !this.form;
    });
  }
 }
 return radios;
};
```

They use it inside their widget( "ui.button" ) click event handler when the button type is "radio", so that they can remove the "ui-state-active" class from all the other buttons.